# RestTemplate with encoded parameters

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, spring-rest, auth0

I need to send an HTTP request to an authentication provider (Auth0). I want to get one specific user by its email address.

The request has to go to:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ..." https://.../users?q=email%3A%22mymail%40abc.de%22&search_engine=v2
```

I tried my luck with RestTemplate (Spring):

```
public void doSomething() {
    ...

    Map<String, String> requestMap = new HashMap<>();
    requestMap.put("q", "email%3A%22mymail%40abc.de%22");
    requestMap.put("search_engine", "v2");

    RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplateForRequestMap();

    HttpHeaders headers = getHeaders();
    HttpEntity<Map<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestMap, headers);

    ResponseEntity<UserInfo[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(URI.create(baseApiUrl + "users"), HttpMethod.GET, request, UserInfo[].class);

    ...
}

private RestTemplate getRestTemplateForRequestMap() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
    messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

    return restTemplate;
}
```

Looks like the value of the `q` parameter needs to be encoded (they call it "Lucene query syntax"). I tried different variations. I even put them "hardcoded" encoded.

However it seems like the `q` parameter isn't working as the result includes not only the user with the specified email address but all users.
Headers are fine (otherwise I would get no user at all).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the map of your request parameters on on an overloaded method of `restTemplate.exchange` :

```
    ResponseEntity<UserInfo[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(URI.create(baseApiUrl + "users"), HttpMethod.GET,
 request, UserInfo[].class,requestMap);
```

Comment: Are you missing something? Method cannot be resolved. Looks like I can't do it with that parameters.

Comment: no , I am using `org.springframework.http.HttpEntity`,  `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;` and i can resolve the method

Comment: Working when converting the URI toString. However I get the same result (all users instead of the one specified).

Comment: are you sure this is the correct mail adress `email%3A%22mymail%40abc.de%22` ?

Comment: Yes, I copied it from the "interactive API" on their page where those parameters are working (btw: it's anonymised).

Comment: can you try : requestMap.put("q", "email:\"mymail@abc.de\"");

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
 UriComponentsBuilder builder;
        try {            
String emailEncoded = URLEncoder.encode("email:" + email, "UTF-8");
                builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
                        .queryParam("include_fields", "true")
                        .queryParam("search_engine", "v3")
                        .queryParam("q", emailEncoded);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                .....
            }

            HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = HttpUtility.getHttpEntity(jwtToken);
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class);
```